# Automating WSUS via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, wsus

I have written a script with the intention of quickly managing the [WSUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services) process, and I have a few things I hard coded in, but would rather get with PowerShell. In particular, the 'Target' groups for Approve-WsusUpdate.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
#Select Target Group for Update Approval:

$TargetComputerGroups = "All Computers", "Unassigned Computers", "Clients", "Servers", "Test", "View Templates"

$UserPrompt = @"

Please select a Computer Group from the below options:

1) All Computers (Selects all of the below)
2) Unassigned Computers
3) Clients
4) Servers
5) Test
6) View Templates

Enter selection
"@

###Record user selection to varirable
$TargetComputerGroupTemp = Read-Host -Prompt $UserPrompt

###Convert their choice to the correct 0-index array value.
$TargetComputerIndex = $TargetComputerGroupTemp -1

$ComputerTarget = $TargetComputerGroups[$TargetComputerIndex]
```

Is there a 'get-targets' command which will create an array of available target groups? This way I could remove the manual declaration of `$TargetComputerGroups`.

In addition, I would like to make the `$UserPrompt` a better set of code (again avoiding manual declarations). I think doing something like `'$i for $i in $TargetComputerGroups' write-host 'Press 1 for i'`

That being said, I am VERY new to this, so I don't know the best way to do that (ideally mapping their selection to the correct group in that statement!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with PowerShell, but you need to have the WSUS administration console installed on the machine too.

You can then do the following.

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")

$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer(“wsus_server”,$False)

$wsus
```

You can then get a list of target groups with

```
$wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups()
```

Or select a group with

```
$targetgroup = $wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups() | ? {$_.Name -eq "some target name"}
```

There is much more information in *[Use PowerShell to Perform Basic Administrative Tasks on WSUS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/17/use-powershell-to-perform-basic-administrative-tasks-on-wsus.aspx)*, but the above information will get you information on the groups.

Comment: Oooph. The more I try to give in to powershell the more I get disappointed =/ I'll accept this if I don't hear anything else by the end of the day. The link looks great and thank you for your help!

Comment: Give in to it :) I find myself using it for a lot. Often even if there isn't a native powershell command someone has written a module for it.

Comment: Yeah, I just wish the UpdateServices Module had the ability to Get-TargetGroups or something like that because it's a property on 3 other commands within it lol =/ I'm also new to this powershell stuff and that ' [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")' is SO weird to me still.
Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Drifter104 said, there isn't yet a PowerShell module available for managing WSUS, although one will be included in the next Windows Server release (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826166.aspx); meanwhile, you need to import the .NET assembly for managing WSUS and use that; one of the greatest features in PowerShell is, even if it doesn't include native cmdlets for performing a given task, you have access to the full .NET enviroment from it, and you can actually do anything you would be able to do from a .NET application.

About the scripting part: once you get the names of your WSUS groups in an array, dinamically building the list shown to your users is quite easy; simply loop through the array and use an index for the selection number:

```
Write-Host Please select a Computer Group from the below options:

$i = 1

foreach($g in $TargetComputerGroups)
{
    Write-Host Press $i for $g
    $i++
}

$sel = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter selection: "
```